# Can I fly from USA to EU during Trump's COVID-19 Europe ban?

Tags: usa, air-travel, eu, switzerland, covid-19

USA banned all flights from EU. My BF already flew Athens-Zurich-Miami, and he returns at the end of March (within the 30 days Corona virus ban), again via Zurich.

Is he is going to be affected by USA's ban, with the data we have as of 12 of March?

Comment: Your question title asks if you can fly but your question talks about your boyfriend. Which is it?

Comment: Does it make a difference @Traveller? My best friend. I decided to phrase the question as such, so that future readers can easily find it.

Comment: Well yes it does - it’s impossible to tell what citizenship you’re talking about, for example, which might affect the answer. And there is no ‘ban’ on flights, there’s a ban on a particular set of people entering the US.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Contrary to some statements, flights have not been banned. Only some (well, many) people are banned.

As there will be a huge drop in the number of people travelling on those flights, many flights will be cancelled, but at this stage there is no indication that they will stop altogether.

Airlines are scrambling to try to adjust their schedules to the demand, to changing bans and regulations, you should monitor the status of the flights, as rebooking may be necessary.

Comment: Hmm, so you mean that USA is not banning the airline from flying from Miami to Zurich, and then Athens, is just that because of the circumstances, the airline might probably decide to cancel the flight.. Laconically, isn't that what your answer says, or I I got it wrong?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. The Lufthansa group, which includes Swiss Air, has now announced that all but 6 flights to/from the US are cancelled effective March 14th, including Miami-Zurich. Rebooking will be necessary, but it’s still possible to make the trip (unless things change again by then). I would recommend getting back ASAP.

Comment: IIRC the US is also restricting which airports flights from the Schengen area can land at. I would expect in practice most if not all remaining flights to the Schengen area will departs from those airports.